# Online service for bufferizing remote files and changing download link

Tags: download-manager, hosted

I'm looking for a service (not for self-hosting) that gets a download link and in its server-side downloads that file *completely* and provides a new download link to that file, which points to the file that is hosted in that online service not the original source.

```
+----------------+       +-----------------+
| Online service | ----- | Original source |
+----------------+       +-----------------+
        |
        |
     +----+
     | me |
     +----+
```

Why such a service could be useful?

- Some servers are too far from me and downloading from them is too slow.
- Bypassing blocking.

Note that I do *not* need a web proxy, because they making delay despite of original source delay, so using them leads to much more delay.

Comment: @Thomas Found a rather good service before. https://zbigz.com/

Comment: You can add that as an answer. Chances are it gets upvoted :-) and you can even accept your own answer after 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

- [URL Droplet](https://www.urldroplet.com) is a paid service that enables saving files from web locations to your Dropbox account.
- [Download to Dropbox Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-to-dropbox/mklccdhnpppcmbpbkaanmamjfmmefbnp)
- There are IFTTT recipes for downloading a file from a URL to [various](https://ifttt.com/channels/dropbox/actions/26-add-file-from-url) [cloud](https://ifttt.com/channels/google_drive/actions/78-upload-file-from-url) [storage](https://ifttt.com/channels/onedrive/actions/94-add-file-from-url) services, however, there is a 30 MB file size limit.